# How to navigate from one tab to another tab by clicking a link or url in IONIC?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, tabs

Suppose I have two tabs in my app, One is `tab-one` and another is `tab-two` now i want navigate from tab-one's view(one.html) to tab tab-two's view(two.html).
I tried $state.go(), $location, $window.location but nothing works , I can navigate to any views successfully if all are under same **tab** even though the **controllers** are different, but navigation does not work if views belongs different **tabs**, following code shows states defined in app.js file

```
.state('tab.tasklist', {
    url: '/tasklist',
    views: {
      'tab-one@tab': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/one.html',
        controller: 'OneCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

.state('tab.ccpo', {
    url: '/ccpo',
    views: {
      'tab-two@tab': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/two.html',
        controller: 'AnotherCtrl'     
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it in the controller. But, I know it works if you use the `ui-sref` attribute in a link (doesn't have to be an `<a>`-tag though. See below)

For example:
Put a button in your `one.html` template with the state name in the `ui-sref`:

```
<button ui-sref="tab.ccpo">Second tab</button>
```

and it'll take you from your first tab to the second.

Answer (score 0):

as you have two states for each tab, 
in **OneCtrl** , you need to write `$state.go('tab.ccpo');` when ever you want to navigate